# It is possible recover a deleted contact?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

By mistake, I deleted a contact in my phone. The contact was not synchronised with Gmail so I can't recover it.

Is there some method, software or technique to recover?
What's the maximum time to recover deleted data?

I was reading there is sofware that can recover it. An other option to do that  is with my phone "rooted". What could be better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has recover some contacts and the call historical  with a software "Android Data Recovery", i am amazed for this, it has some other functions.

Now, the joke, or in other words the irony i has not  recover the contact that i need, it is from a girl.
Greetings ;)